# What is the best way to transfer file from FTP to AWS s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to copy **100-200GB** files from a secure FTP server (here ftp server with username and password is secure FTP server for me) to AWS S3 bucket. Obviously, I don't want to download and upload file. So, I looked into [FTP2Cloud](https://www.ftp2cloud.com/), but it is in beta phase and the limit is only 100MB. Also, I've also looked into **s3cmd**, but I couldn't figure out a way to connect to secure ftp server. So, I'm stuck on transferring the files. Can somebody help me in transferring files from FTP to S3 without explicitly downloading and uploading data?

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the ftp server ?

Comment: Nope. I've username and password only to access the server.

Comment: without server access, you'll need to download from ftp and upload to s3. You can optimize this by streaming the data, and you can increase the speed by using an EC2 instance.

Comment: @Abhishek This is a bit of a long shot but you can use the AWS S3 PHP SDK to write a script that uploads files from a location on your server. Then on, upload this script to your server using ftp and then hit the url in the browser to execute the script. It will upload all files directly from your server. Such a PHP script will be heavy on your server resources so I am not sure you can do this if you do not have permissions to configure PHP on your server.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman I don't have permissions to run php scripts on server. I can run JAVA code though. So, some inputs I might have to download and upload data via streaming. Any other way?

Comment: @Abhishek You can also code the same script using Java with AWS Java SDK.

Comment: @NomanUrRehman tried it. But I'm interested in more efficient way to do or use existing tools, so that I don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: how about using aws cli? https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

Answer (score 0):

Create an EC2 instance, download to that instance and upload to S3.